# Нагрузка на процессор при добавлении картинки в imageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    viewInspector.setContextOptions(item);
    contextMenuInspector.setContextMenuItemsOptions(item, tag, textViews, imageViews, buttons, viewInspector, ID, editText, button);
    if(item.getItemId() == 5) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case GALLERY_REQUEST:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(selectedImage)
                        .into(imageViews[ID]);
                selectedImage = null;
            }
    }
}
```

В первом методе я вызываю активность выборки одной фотографии. А во втором методе, я добавляю в нужный ImageView (созданный из кода, его нет в xml файле) эту картинку использую библиотеку picasso.

XML файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/android_main_context"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Подтвердить"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

В итоге, когда я создал много imageView и загрузил туда фотографии, при пролистывании экрана, начинает очень сильно нагружаться процессор. На Android monitor это явно показано. Чем больше фотографий, тем сильнее тормозит телефон.

Каким образом это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы создаете программно ImageView и добавляете его в контейнер? если так, то почему не использовать RecyclerView ?

Comment: Это повысит производительность?

Comment: в 100500 раз...